# Multiclass GridSearch

Tags: scikit-learn

```
self.train_label_df = pd.DataFrame(train_label)
self.test_label_df = pd.DataFrame(test_label)

data = self.train_df.values

label = self.train_label_df.values

(68914, 249)

(68914, 3)

clf = RandomForestClassifier()

param_grid = {'n_estimators': [100],'criterion': ['entropy'],'max_depth': [10] }

gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=clf, param_grid=param_grid, cv=5, scoring='roc_auc')
```

**ValueError: Only one class present in y_true. ROC AUC score is not defined in that case.**

I need to make a classifier with 3-class,but in the gridsearch with `roc_auc`, some error always show up, any one can help you?

Comment: the cv = 5 you used will use a simple KFold internally in which it may happen that training fold consists of only single class. You should use a stratified approach to maintain class balance in the cross validation split. See http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html. Also show some samples of data